# How to handle multiple emails being sent with nodemailer without blocking main thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, backend, nodemailer

I have an node application with multiple routes and all cases are being handled with asynchronous functions to handle them but I am looking forward for a logic/idea how to proceed when multiple emails are to be sent with respective email content like username, image, etc. with nodemailer (being iterated).

Basically I have an array/object which has all content to send each email address but if I allow to execute then that loop will block the main thread and thus next requests/tasks won't be able to  achieve.

Looking forward to get some idea.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd make queues and after each job, prioritize the queues and determine if you can send the next email.

Comment: So the idea is, each request the server gets gets organized into different queues, so one can be for emails only, one for login requests and etc... When you finish a login request, you clear the login queue of that request and check your queue handler for what job to do next.

Comment: I second that. Organizing work into queues makes it easier to scale up your application in the future. For example, you could eventually offload the sending of e-mails to a separate process/server altogether.

Comment: You get about 400 request/s a core with Node.JS so it would be ideal to offload tasks at anytime to other servers and keeping it secure. If not one can rely on load-balancers and writing a queue that slips an email request in every 5-10 requests. so it's not too hoggish.

Comment: How to check whether the thread is actually empty so that I will start triggering some mails out of 100 and then stop and then resume leftouts ? Is it like global queue to store them and then retrieve and work on the task?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function after sending the response.

```
myController = (req, res, next) => {
   /* some code */

   res.send("OK");
   callMailServicesHere(myArray);

}
```

Comment: but the fxn callMailServicesHere when executes it still has the myArray which will start iterating and starting send email which will block the stack to allow on other tasks on server.

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood your question. Then, blanknamefornow's answer will do I think. Or you can separate your mail services as micro-service. In that way, you won't worry about event loop blocking and your mails will be independent of the rest of the server.